# What broke the contribution thermometer blocks in the CiviCRM 4.7 upgrade? How to resolve the issue?

Tags: civicontribute

Upon upgrading from CiviCRM 4.6.x to 4.7.x, the CiviCRM contribution thermometer within a Drupal block stopped functioning. Please see the current state of the block:

[image]

I have found some posts that sound related to what we are seeing:

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17965

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17970

I posted a reply to the CRM-17965 post as to trying the suggested patch back on CiviCRM 4.7.3, which did not change what we see displayed in the block... however it did achieve the test URL displaying HTML rather than nothing, so I would have hoped for some change in behavior of the actual Drupal block.

Suggestions how to get this resolved?

I am thankful,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the exact same issue you described and used the fix that Marty Wright described in https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17965 to resolve on several sites.  Once the file change was made, I did have to clear my Drupal cache for the site to update.  Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much... that helped very much. Yes, on our Dev copy of the site it helped right away. Prod still had issues. I found that with Civi 4.7.x, no longer can we connect the extern/widget.php URL over https://  Over secure protocol, it was rewriting the URL and bringing up a copy of the site homepage. Dropping back to http:// however solves the issue for prod as well. :-) Yes, CiviCRM team, please get this fix updated / committed to prod releases. Oh, and I patched both Drupal.php and Drupal6.php as we run on D6 still.